# Tableview cell layout incorrectly after the tableview reloaddata

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wonder why this happens, first I load the view like following:
[image]

But after I scroll the tableview and tap the another button above the tableview which shows "趣味型返点" on title, triggering the table reload data. And the layout shows following :
[image]

It layout incorrectly, but it become correct instantly after I scroll or even tap the tableview like following:

[image]

Why is this happens?

Note:The incorrect layout won't happen if I don't scroll the tableview(or scroll offset is 0 ) before I tap another to reload data.

Comment: I have try that setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay on cell before return it,  or scroll to top before reloading the data.

Answer (score 0):

did you use the same `UITableView` to load different data ?

If you do, you may try set offset to zero before you reload data.

Comment: yes, I use the same tableview, is there a better way to do?And, do you mean set content offset to zero? I have tried it and doesn't work T T

Comment: try call [tableview layoutIfNeeded]; and setContentOffset to 0 ?

Comment: It works! Thank you, and self.tableView.scrollToRow to top also works. I wonder why is the reason behind.